# Return split string obtained from a multi line text file

Tags: javascript

I was trying to return data obtained from a text file by reading it and then popping everything after the comma. I tried to use `split(',').pop()` but this only works for 1 string. How can I make it iterate on every line in a text file then return the popped string. I included an example below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
Example txt file:
orange,001
bannana,002
apples,003

would return:
001
002
003
```

```js
//something like this but for everyline in the text file.
const reader = fs.readFileSync('filePath', 'utf-8');
const popped = reader.split(',').pop();
console.log(popped)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to split by lines and then get every item after the `,` using `map`

```js
const txt = `orange,001
bannana,002
apples,003`

const result = txt.split("\n").map(x => x.split(",")[1])
console.log(result);
```

Comment: how can I join the mapped return to new line.@jamiec

Comment: @anon20010813 Im not sure I understand what you mean - do you want the result to be one string like `001,002,003`?

Comment: Nah I meant every result on a new line but I figured it out. ```txt.split("\n").map(x => x.split("=")[1]).join('\n')```. Thanks for the help.@jamiec

Comment: @anon20010813 ah yeah exactly, you can join the array back together to make a string exactly as you said

Answer (score 1):

```js
const reader = fs.readFileSync('filePath', 'utf-8');
const lines = reader.split('\n');
lines.forEach((line)=>{
 const popped = line.split(',').pop();
 console.log(popped)
})
```